# JQuery Autosubmit Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JQuery/Javascript how to Parse HTML using a Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655229/jquery-javascript-how-to-parse-html-using-a-get)

I have the following code that is working:

```
$.getJSON('json/shares.json', function(data) {
var items = [];

$.each(data.Shares, function(key, val) {
items.push('<option id="' + val.shareName+ '">' + val.shareName+ '</option>');
});

  $('<select/>', {
    'id': 'shares_select',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('#shares');
});

$.get('lon_shares.html', function(data){     
$(data).appendTo('#shares');  
});
```

This will create a dropdown list using a JSON file.  I need it to autosubmit when a selection is made and then get the relevant html file, so if they choose "lon" from the dropdown the file is "lon_shares.html" and if they choose "par" it's "par_shares.html" and so on.

I am new to JQuery and Javascript so please give examples of how it needs to look including my code thanks.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I think my earlier question was more complicated and I've tried to simplify it as I don't understand the answers to that and couldn't get them to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger submit on form on select box change.

```
 $.getJSON('json/shares.json', function(data) {
        var items = [];
        $.each(data.Shares, function(key, val) {
               items.push('<option id="' + val.shareName+ '">' + val.shareName+ '</option>');
          });
        $('<select/>', {
          'id': 'shares_select',
          html: items.join('')
         }).appendTo('#shares')
         .change(function(){    
              $('form').trigger('submit');         
               $.get( this.value +'_shares.html', function(data){     
                     $(data).appendTo('#shares');  
               });
         });
});
```

Comment: `$("##shares select")` ?

Comment: Thanks, so do I simply replace my $.get('lon_shares.html', function(data){     
$(data).appendTo('#shares');  
});

Comment: @davidjwest I made change in my code. This should work. but I am not sure about form submit.

Comment: @Shusi - Thanks but it doesn't seem to work, I simply replaced my code with that above, is that correct?  I don't get a drop down at all now.

Comment: @davidjwest Sorry, I forgot to close braces '})';

Comment: @Shusi, thanks that's better, I see the dropdown and it *seems* to autosubmit as it's going back to the default when I choose something but it's not bringing in any of the html content, the get doesn't seem to work or append anything.  Could be me doing something wrong I suppose!

Comment: can you share more code (html). are you preventing page refresh on form submit?

Comment: There isn't really any HTML involved, I've taken everything out of the page to test and it's the same, the get isn't displaying anything.

Comment: @Shusi, I've just tried again with no HTML other than the <div> and still the same, any more ideas please?  Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Suppose this is the html
<select id="share-list">
</select>

<div id="shares">
</div>

//this should be in script tag
$.getJSON('json/shares.json', function(data) {
    //This clears previous items in the dropdown
    $("select#share-list").html('')

    $.each(data.Shares, function(key, val) {
        $("select#share-list").append('<option value="' + val.shareName+ '">' + val.shareName+ '</option>');
    });

});

//Binding a change event to the dropdown
$("select#share-list").change(function(e) {
    var el = $(e.currentTarget);
    var share_name = el.attr('value');
    var page = share_name+'.html';

    $.get(page, function(data){     
        $(data).appendTo('#shares');  
    });
});
```